# Does male or female DNA contain more information?

Tags: dna

I wonder if the male or the female DNA contains more or less information than the other?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/do-men-and-women-have-the-same-number-of-genes

Answer (score 4):

Define "information" — females have more base pairs and more individual genes because X's are larger than Y's, but males have a large number of unique loci and thus unique genes, because they have an X and Y chromosome.